# Deep Linking with IOS and Android Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I need to implement deeplinking within my app. My problem is there is little to no resources on the internet.

Where can I start studying about deep linking implementation?

I am using Angular as my framework.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ask in their [slack channel](https://app.slack.com/client/T0L97VCSY/C0L9EEURY/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nativescript-urlhandler](https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler) plugin

```
tns plugin add nativescript-urlhandler
```

The instructions in the plugin docs shows, how you may handle non-http link. There may be additional configurations required for Http links, [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) / [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) setup.

Using the plugin you may read the url that was used to open the app, based on the parameters you may perform navigation.

Comment: Supposed I already added well-know file on my server, what steps do I need to take on my NS App? Would nativescript-urlhandler enough for that?

Comment: Yes, well-known file is for Apple to validate. Then you may just add the entitlement file (`App_Resources/iOS/<appname>.entitlements`) with associated-domains capabilities to your project. If you are not sure about the syntax, just do it on Xcode by opening the native project in platforms folder, then copy the file to app resources.

Comment: do you have a sample well-known file?

Comment: You will find the example in the iOS docs linked about, it's JSON file with name `apple-app-site-association`.

Comment: HI @Manoj I managed to create an entitlement file from xcode and it is working, My question is that what is <appname> for making a file for it in App/Resources folder? Thnks

Comment: It's your app's name, mostly same name as your Xcode project.

Comment: HI  @Manoj, Im sorry for another question. But the entitlement file is not being copied on tns prepare ios --release.

Comment: Its actually being copied but not on <app-name>/ instead it is being copied on <app-name>/Resources folder.

Comment: NVM I already found a solution. I put the value on Info.plist.